# how to get id of image selected in jquery

Tags: jquery, image

I have below code in my html body.

```
<ul>
<li>
<div>
<a href=javascript:contactsAction() > 
<img src="contactimageloc1.jpg"  id="image_id1  "    width="140px" height="160px"/>
</a>
<br> 
 firstName     lastName  ,   title   
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div>
<a href=javascript:contactsAction() > 
<img src="contactimageloc.jpg"  id="image_id2"    width="140px" height="160px"/>
</a>
<br> 
 firstName     lastName  ,   title   
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

When ever a image is clicked I want to know that image id.

```
<script>
function  contactsAction(){

alert('On Image click function'+$(':image'));
alert('Inside $(this).find(a:first).attr(id) :'+$(this).find('a:first').attr('id'));

alert('image $(this).children(a).attr(id): '+$(this).children('a').attr('id'));

alert('image $(this).children(a).eq(0).attr(id): '+$(this).children('a').eq(0).attr('id'));

alert('$(this).children().length: '+ $(this).children().length);
alert('image id: '+$(this).attr('id').value);

}
</script>
```

For `alert('$(this).children().length: '+ $(this).children().length);` I am getting output as 0.

And for all other alerts I am getting undefined as output.

Can any one please help me how can I get the image id of selected image.

Thanks

Comment: Please indent your code properly so that others can read it.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).children().attr('id')`

Comment: Please provide more than code when you answer a question in order to provide context.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `contactsAction`, `this` will refer to `window`, because you are calling it as normal function.

I suggest to give those links a proper URL and attach the event handler with jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(event) { // use an appropriate selector here
    event.preventDefault();    // don't follow the URL
    console.log('Image clicked: ' + $(this).children('img').attr('id'));
});
```

Please have a look at the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) and [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

`(this).id` will give you the id of the element in question.

```
function  contactsAction(
){

alert (this.id); //This will tell you the id of the element

alert('On Image click function'+$(':image'));
alert('Inside $(this).find(a:first).attr(id) :'+$(this).find('a:first').attr('id'));

alert('image $(this).children(a).attr(id): '+$(this).children('a').attr('id'));

alert('image $(this).children(a).eq(0).attr(id): '+$(this).children('a').eq(0).attr('id'));

alert('$(this).children().length: '+ $(this).children().length);
alert('image id: '+$(this).attr('id').value);

}
```